# annotations to check null and whitespaces in spring boot

Tags: rest, spring-boot, annotations

Is there any annotation in spring boot which checks for null as well as whitespaces for a field in json request .
As of now I have added @NotNull annotation to a field, it works for null value  but gets success if I add space or tab. Is there any wayto check for them as well

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is: `@NotBlank`

See here:

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/beanvalidation/api/javax/validation/constraints/NotBlank.html

Comment: the above mentioned NotBlank is deprecated. The one which is in use is  javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank. I havedownloaded the jar and included it in my code, but still code doesnt seem to work.It is not throwing any error for empty field

Comment: The one I linked above is javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank. I'm using it in my project currently and it does work. I can't help you further without seeing more of your code.